# popen() implementation,fd leaks,and vfork()

Tags: popen, vfork

In the glibc implementation of `popen()`, it specifies that

> The popen() function shall ensure that any streams from previous popen() calls that remain open in the parent process are closed in the new child process.

Why? If the purpose is to avoid fd leaks, why not just close all open fds?

The glibc implementation of `popen()` uses `fork()`. Although there are `dup2()` and `close()` calls between `fork()` and `exec()`, is it possible to replace `fork()` by `vfork()` to improve performance?

Is the Linux implementation of `popen()` based on `fork()` rather than `vfork()`?  Why (or why not)?

I'm going to write a bidirectional version of `popen()`, which returns two `FILE*`: one for read and one for write. How do I implement it correctly? It should be thread safe and no fd leaks. It is better if it is fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) is obsolete (removed from POSIX2008), and [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) is quite efficient, since it uses [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques.

[popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) cannot close *all* opened files, because it does not know them and cannot know which are relevant. Imagine a program which gets a `socket` and pass its file descriptor as an argument to the `popen`-ed command (or simply `popen("time cat /etc/issue >&9; date","r")`....). See also [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) with `FD_CLOEXEC`, [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) with `O_CLOEXEC`, [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

<sup>File descriptors are program-wide and process-wide scare resources and it is your responsability to manage them correctly. You should know which fd-s should be closed in your child process before `execve`. If you know what program is `execve`-d and what fds it needs, you can `close` all other fds (or most of them, perhaps with `for (int i=STDERR_FILENO+1; i<64; i++) (void) close(i);`) before `execve`.</sup>

If you are coding a reusable library, *document* its policy regarding file descriptors (and any other global process-wide resources) and probably use `FD_CLOEXEC` on any file descriptors it is obtaining itself (not as explicit argument or data), e.g. for internal use.

It looks like you are reinventing [p2open](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3gen/p2open/) (then you probably need to understand the implementation details of your `FILE` in your C standard library, or else use [fdopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) with care and caution); you might find some implementation of it. Beware, the process using that probably need to have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. above [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ...) to avoid a potential deadlock (with both parent and child processes blocked on reading).

Did you consider using some existing event loop infrastructure (e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from GTK, etc....)?

BTW Linux has several [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementations for its [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). The [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is quite common, but there is [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) and several others. Study the source code of your libc.

Comment: Is vfork() a faster version of fork()? vfork() doesn't need to copy the page tables of the parent process.  When the parent process uses a lot of memory, fork() might cause OOM error, unless OS is configured to allow memory overcommit.

Comment: Not really, and a parent process using a *lot* of memory should not use `system` or `popen` (but code carefully using `fork` and perhaps unmapping memory before)... A better way is to have enough swap space which is unexpensive today.

Comment: I don't know about p2open. I don't need event loop, because the read and write operations are performed in separate threads.

Comment: Then you should not bother about defining `p2open` and just use `pipe`, `fork`, `execve`, `waitpid`

Comment: So popen() indeed have fd leaks if not all fds are set to O_CLOEXEC, right? It is not practical to control the code outside my library. In my own implementation can I simply close all open fds between fork() and exec()?

Comment: It is not a leak, it is desired feature, as I explained.

Comment: I still wonder whether there is way to correctly implement popen that can efficiently close all fds inheriting from parent process, without requiring all fds are marked FD_CLOEXEC

Comment: @user3547691: [`subprocess.Popen` in Python has `pass_fds` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) that specifies a set of file descriptors to keep open -- everything else (except 0,1,2) is closed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This is perfectly what I need. But how is it implemented in C? And what's it's performance? Does it need to brute force search all open fds and close each one by one?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I suspect that python create all fds with O_CLOEXEC flag by default. It may be a language support?

Comment: @user3547691: [CPython is open-source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/08d0cc23fb00/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#l247). Yes, it may close all open(or not) fds one by one. The specific implementation may depend on platform. Yes, high-level API prefers `O_CLOEXEC` by default.

Comment: @user3547691: here's some rationale for the feature: [PEP 0446 -- Make newly created file descriptors non-inheritable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The CPython code is a good reference. Thank you

Comment: While it's true that vfork has been marked as obsolete, I don't think there is a good reason for it, because vfork not requiring copying the parent's page tables is actually a huuuuge advantage in memory-hungry processes. You claiming that a memory-hungry process should be using manual fork with memory management is honestly nonsense.